# RewriteRule into sub directories is failing

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, this works (http://example.com/@user):

> RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]*$
>   find.php?twitter=$1 [QSA,L]

and this (http://example.com/api/@user):

> RewriteRule ^api/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]*$ twitter.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

does not. I'm not sure why, but it seems whenever I try to do this, it redirects to http://example.com/@user's function if that makes sense. Basically, the rewrite rule is ignoring the "api/" prefix.

Comment: Have you put the second rule first in your htaccess ?

Comment: yes, doesn't seem to be the issue. Erors also occurs with other htaccess rules that have a subdirectory prefix, even when they do not have a counter part without a prefix. The main issue is RewriteEngine isn't figuring out subdirectories. I believe its my syntax at fault.

Comment: can you give an example of before and after for the second rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following syntax on a test server, and it worked perfectly find. In if doesn't works for you, the problem is probably not with the regex…

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^api/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ twitter.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$     find.php?twitter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: perhaps you can explain why. http://gist.github.com/5b0099f6aafc6c6a1b7b is my htaccess file. Any of the RewriteRules that begin with foo/ are not working, and the api one is specific seems to opt to follow the rule of the corresponding rule.